# Zoho error "`400 Bad Request`": mandatory param missing

Tags: php, json, laravel, zoho

Trying to make search record api call but giving error "mandatory param missing" even specifying phone in form_params.

```
public function execute(){
        $client = new Client();
        $phone = 9XXXXXXXX9;
        $token['Authorization']='Zoho-oauthtoken '.'1000.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        $deals = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.zohoapis.in/crm/v2/Leads/search', [
            'form_params' => [
                'phone' => $phone
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization'=>$token
            ]
           
        ]); 
        dd($deals);
}
```

What is the issue Here?
Thanks in advance.

[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeK5t.png)

Comment: The criteria parameter is required but you’ve not provided it as part of your request.

Comment: MANDATORY_NOT_FOUNDHTTP 400
mandatory param missing
Resolution: Specify any of the mandatory parameters (criteria/email/phone/word) in your request.

am i doing right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to make a `GET` request but specifying your parameters as if it were a `POST`.

Use `query` on your `$params`:

```
$deals = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.zohoapis.in/crm/v2/leads/search', [
    'query' => [ // <-- query, not form_params
        'phone' => $phone
    ],
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => $token
    ]
]);
```

You might want to consider using the official [`ZOHO CRM API`](https://github.com/zoho/zohocrm-php-sdk) to make your life a little simpler.